# I was trying to implement the Minimax Algorithm to tic tac toe in python but it just doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe, minimax

So I was trying to implement the Minimax Algorithm to tic tac toe in python but it doesn't work and I have no idea why. It's the version when I start as the X and the program goes second as O. I have an array called game_state in which every field is covered, 1 if X is there, 2 if O is there and 0 if it's empty. My function checkwin() returns 1 if X won, -1 if O won, 0 if there was a tie and None if the game isn't finished. Point is a structure to hold a move value and display O further in the code, but that seems to be working flawlessly.

I call it here:

```
def best_move():
global game_state
best_score = math.inf
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if game_state[i][j] == 0:
            game_state[i][j] = 2
            score = minimax(game_state, 0, False)
            game_state[i][j] = 0
            if score < best_score:
                best_score = score
                move = Point(i, j, i*3+j)

game_state[move.i][move.j] = 2
return move.number
```

And that's my minimax function:

```
def minimax(game_state, depth, is_maximizing):
result = checkwin(game_state)
if result is not None:
    return result

if is_maximizing:
    best_score = -math.inf
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if game_state[i][j] == 0:
                game_state[i][j] = 1
                score = minimax(game_state, depth+1, False)
                game_state[i][j] = 0
                best_score = max(score, best_score)
    return best_score
else:
    best_score = math.inf
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if game_state[i][j] == 0:
                game_state[i][j] = 2
                score = minimax(game_state, depth+1, True)
                game_state[i][j] = 0
                best_score = min(score, best_score)
    return best_score
```

Answer (score 0):

You are maximizing the variable best_score in minimax function.
Whereas you are minimizing the best_score in best_move function, which is contradicting.

You should also maximize best_score in best_move function:

```
def best_move():
global game_state
best_score = -math.inf                   #This is changed
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if game_state[i][j] == 0:
            game_state[i][j] = 2
            score = minimax(game_state, 0, False)
            game_state[i][j] = 0
            if score > best_score:       #This is changed
                best_score = score
                move = Point(i, j, i*3+j)

game_state[move.i][move.j] = 2
return move.number
```

Also in best_move, the player is 2('O'), and you are passing 'False' in minimax as minimax(game_state, depth+1, False). This will run the else statement in minimax function which is also of player 2('O'). This is also an error. You should use:

```
def minimax(game_state, depth, is_maximizing):
result = checkwin(game_state)
if result is not None:
    return result

if is_maximizing:
    best_score = -math.inf
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if game_state[i][j] == 0:
                game_state[i][j] = 2                         #This is changed
                score = minimax(game_state, depth+1, False)
                game_state[i][j] = 0
                best_score = max(score, best_score)
    return best_score
else:
    best_score = math.inf
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if game_state[i][j] == 0:
                game_state[i][j] = 1                         #This is changed
                score = minimax(game_state, depth+1, True)
                game_state[i][j] = 0
                best_score = min(score, best_score)
    return best_score
```